# Graph returned an error: Can't load URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I was using Facebook login API since last 8 months and was working fine. Today, without changing any settings or any code the API is returning error.

```
Graph returned an error: Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.
```

I don't understand what happened, NOTHING has been changed.

I cross-checked all settings and domain name is also same. App ID and Client secret is also correct.

Comment: We has exactly the same problem now. Did you found any solution?

Comment: Yes. I found the solution.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem you should go into:

developers.facebook.com -> your app -> PRODUCTS > Facebook Login -> Settings -> Client OAuth Settings -> Valid OAuth redirect URIs

And add hire valid OAuth redirect URI (URI include also query parameter)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, solve it by updating facebook PHP SDK.